# Grub Configuration for OpenVZ?

Tags: centos, boot, openvz, grub

I am trying to get OpenVZ working on my server but I am having problems. I am getting the error 'Running kernel is not OpenVZ kernel.' every time I install OpenVZ. My server is running CentOS 64bit.

My existing grub file is below:

```
timeout=10
splashimage=(hd0,0)/grub/splash.xpm.gz
hiddenmenu
default=2
title CentOS (2.6.18-238.5.1.el5.028stab085.3)
root (hd0,0)
kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.18-238.5.1.el5.028stab085.3 ro root=/dev/sda3 rhgb
initrd /initrd-2.6.18-238.5.1.el5.028stab085.3.img

title CentOS (2.6.18-194.32.1.el5.centos.plusxen)
root (hd0,0)
kernel /xen.gz-2.6.18-194.32.1.el5.centos.plus
module /vmlinuz-2.6.18-194.32.1.el5.centos.plusxen ro root=/dev/sda3 rhgb
module /initrd-2.6.18-194.32.1.el5.centos.plusxen.img

title Centos Kernel 2.6.18-194.32.1.el5.centos.plus
root (hd0,0)
kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.18-194.32.1.el5.centos.plus ro root=/dev/sda3 rhgb
initrd /initrd-2.6.18-194.32.1.el5.centos.plus.img
```

Will the above file boot my server into the OpenVZ kernel? I did at one time install Xen I believe which may also be causing a problem. I do not understand how to read the file above so if someone could tell me if the file should boot the server into the OpenVZ kernel or not I would be very happy.

Thanks

Comment: Installing Xen earlier is most likely not the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Grub file reads like this. There are 3 kernels in the list:

- 2.6.18-238.5.1.el5.028stab085.3
- 2.6.18-194.32.1.el5.centos.plusxen
- 2.6.18-194.32.1.el5.centos.plus

The 3rd one will be loaded if manual selection during boot is not made. That's defined by `default=2`.
To load the first one it would be `default=0`.

I can't tell it any of kernels are OpenVZ. On Debian I would see the word "openvz" or "ovz" somewhere in the kernel name.

I normally follow:
http://wiki.openvz.org/Quick_installation

`yum` should configure your Grub automatically.
Did you just run `yum install ovzkernel`...?

Comment: Thank you, yes following your guide I managed to boot using OpenVZ.